# calling program from bat file in a loop

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I am trying to call robocopy in a loop in a bat file:

```
set basedir="C:\tmp"
set src[0]="%basedir%\src\A" 
set src[1]="%basedir%\src\B" 

set target[0]="%basedir%\target\A-out" 
set target[1]="%basedir%\target\B-out" 

set "x=0"
for %%i in (%src%) do (
   robocopy /E  %%src[%x%]%%  %%target[%x%]%%
   echo %%~i
   REM cinst "%%~i"
   set /a "x+=1"   
)
```

But the variables for robocopy are not expanded correctly, what am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct syntax for variable modifiers when using EnableDelayedExpansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322807/correct-syntax-for-variable-modifiers-when-using-enabledelayedexpansion)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the "%%src[%x%]%%" syntax you are using here is valid.

Something like this might work though:

```
SET BaseDir="C:\Tmp"
SET Folders=A B
SET SrcDir=\src\
SET TargetDir=\target\

FOR %%I in (%Folders%) DO (

  ROBOCOPY /E %BaseDir%%SrcDir%%%I %BaseDir%%TargetDir%%%I-Out
  ECHO %%~I
  REM cist "%%~I"

)
```

If your actual folder structure is different than your example above, this might not work as well as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The `%%src[%x%]%%` variable syntax is used when you don't want to enable delayed expansion for some reason, but you still need to use nested variables. There are two ways to expand them properly.

You can use delayed expansion by including the line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of the script and then calling the variable like `!src[%x%]!` and `!target[%x%]!`

You could also simply put a `call` in front of the `robocopy` command, which will also expand the variables properly. `call robocopy /E  %%src[%x%]%%  %%target[%x%]%%`

Answer (score 0):

I too tried to loop ROBOCOPY with 'for'. The only way my batch worked was with 'goto'.

Here is a example that:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions
cls
set /a x=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('TIME/T') do set "var=%%A"

:start
cls

color 73
echo ===================================
DATE /T
echo 1st time: %var%
echo %x% times, last time:
TIME /T
set /a x+=1
echo ===================================

ROBOCOPY C:\Users\source\ C:\Users\destination\ /E /ZB /COPYALL /R:0 /W:0 /V /NP /ETA /TEE /LOG+:C:\Users\log.log
timeout /t 30

goto start
```

- Loop every 30 seconds
- Incremental log
- Display log on the terminal and save into a file
- Display the first and last time you launch the loop